# How to execute bash command on nth flat file column and print it out to output?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I need just basename cmd to be executed on 2'nd column

```
[ora@rac TEST]$ cat test.log | awk '{print $1 " " $2}'
9780c69e13e3dda64c3c6ddce2b37803 /test/test_202007140422_01.zip
73b635c2e852e215a342cba53a323b80 /test/test_202007140422_02.zip
c194efd0fc6381c2a5a92913dae572d6 /test/test_202007140422_03.zip
```

I need something like this:

```
9780c69e13e3dda64c3c6ddce2b37803 test_202007140422_01.zip
73b635c2e852e215a342cba53a323b80 test_202007140422_02.zip
c194efd0fc6381c2a5a92913dae572d6 test_202007140422_03.zip
```

I prefer awk but you can use diff tool if it simple works;)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use space OR slash as the field separator, and print the first and last fields:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]/]' '{print $1, $NF}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this one:

```
while IFS=" " read -r f c; do echo $f $(basename $c); done < test.log
```

and it works for me;)
If you have better idea - please post it below;)